# ERROR: cannot ALTER TABLE because it has pending trigger events while attempting to drop a column in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, liquibase

I wrote a sql tag in my liquibase changeset. this sql code is suppose to make data migration in a table named "Purchase". so i have the following sql queries:

```
UPDATE purchase
SET location_id = (SELECT location_id FROM shop WHERE shop.id = purchase.shop_id);
```

then,

```
ALTER TABLE purchase DROP COLUMN shop_id;
```

but I'm getting the following error while attempting to execute the second query that's supposed to drop column 'shop_id' in table Purchase

```
ERROR: cannot ALTER TABLE  because it has pending trigger events
```

please while is this error thrown and how can i solve it.

in my liquibase changese, my sql tag is written as follow

```
<sql>
     UPDATE purchase
     SET location_id = (SELECT location_id FROM shop WHERE shop.id = purchase.shop_id);        

     ALTER TABLE purchase DROP COLUMN shop_id;
</sql
```

Please can somebody help me? thank's in advance for your help

Comment: have you tried committing before you alter?

Comment: @Joe Love please what is the sql code to commit?

Comment: In straight SQL, it's just "commit" (no quotes). Your library may have a commit command as well, but the straight SQL should work-- the only question is whether or not to begin a new transaction or not with "begin transaction" -- I'd try it first without doing that, but then you're going to have to research your application to see if you need another transaction-- it'll likely work just fine without, but I wouldn't want you to get halfway committed stuff if something fails.

Comment: Ok, i only use "commit" (no quotes) and it works. thanks @Joe Love for your help

Comment: I'll submit as an snwer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you need to commit your changes between the alter and the update.

Try this:

```
UPDATE purchase
SET location_id = (SELECT location_id FROM shop WHERE shop.id = purchase.shop_id);
COMMIT;
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE purchase DROP COLUMN shop_id;
```

The "BEGIN;" is optional, but it sounds like your framework is using a transaction so I'd include it and test to make sure the alter actually "takes".